# Cannot boot into my Windows partition upon installing Ubuntu MATE

Tags: partition, dual-boot

I might have mismatched the partitions somehow. The Windows partition used to show up as a subfolder while I was on Ubuntu, but now I can't find even that.
I will provide any information necessary, as I don't quite know where to even begin. Bootrepair doesn't provide me with any useful data or services.

[image: Here's what gparted shows]

- `sda1` is a failed experiment/fix
- `sda3` is swap
- `sda5` is my Linux

If I could get some advice on how to recover my partition and avoid future mistakes like this, I would be very grateful

EDIT: ran David's command, Windows partition shows up as a folder
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda2
Mounted /dev/sda2 at /media/alex/1600006300004C65.

EDIT: tried mounting under "test", I got this, which is a good sign.
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Comment: One NTFS partition is right there but there are various conditions under which it may not show up in the side bar of the file manager. Could you please [edit] your post to include the output of `udisksctl --mount --block-device /dev/sda2` (replace `sda` with whatever is appropriate if the kernel name of the drive has since changed)? Other options are to attempt to mount the file system from Gnome Disks or GParted. Thanks.

Comment: `sda4` is the extended partition in which `sda5` lives. Extended partitions are an artifact of the ancient MBR partitioning scheme; you cannot use `sda4` for anything -- it's there only because `sda5` needs a place to live.

Comment: What David said. Also, please [edit] your question and clarify what the actual problem is. I don't see anything strange here. Is it just that your Windows partition is no longer shown automatically under Linux? If so, [edit] your question and also show us the output of `sudo mkdir /mnt/test; sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/test`. If there's no output, run `ls /mnt/test` and tell us if your files are there.

Comment: You have erased the windows boot partition [(system partition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_partition_and_boot_partition) , you need to edit your question to get more details .

Comment: Alright, thanks guys, now the real problem is not being able to boot into it.

Comment: Related (on [su]): [Can't boot after deleted System Reserved Partition](https://superuser.com/questions/513557/cant-boot-after-deleted-system-reserved-partition)